# Issues with ER model design

Tags: database, database-design, entity-relationship, erd

I am trying to design a model for our future database of our toys and certain measurements that have to be done post-production. I have trouble grasping how to model this. I have tried multiple ways, but none of them seem optimal and in the end I've always lost out on the connectivity between entities.

What I need to achieve is some kind of meaningful relationship between the following:

- A toy (with some trivial properties).
- A series of toys (multiple toys can be related to one series and a toy can only belong to one series).
- Measurement steps. There are currently 6 of these steps. Each step has its own input parameters and these vary in type as well as in number (eg. only 3 parameters for measurement step 1 and 10 parameters for measurement step 2).
- With each series, a sequence of these measurement steps is defined. Duplicates of tests are allowed (eg. measurement step 1 > measurement step 4 > measurement step 1 is a valid sequence). The sequence along with the parameters must be stored somewhere for future reference.
- Each toy goes through the sequence of measurements that is defined by its series. All of the results must be stored somewhere (for each individual toy).

If I split the measurement steps into their own tables I can't reference them conditionally (as foreign keys) to some other table.
If I try to serialize part of the data I lose the ability to make connections between individual measurement steps, measurement results (at least with queries) etc.

I know people here generally hate/don't answer these kinds of "discussion-like" questions, but I'd ask of you to at least point out what is a good practice in a system where I need to store this locally on a machine, but need a database to hold the data - to move towards serial-like data and just do general relationships where it is easy to do so or keep trying to normalize it as much as possible?

Answer (score 0):

If measurements steps share most of attributes (or are of the same type, like what you called PARAMETERS), and I understood correctly your definitions, I would make something like this.

It could be a starting point.

```
+----------------------------+                    +------------------------------+
|             TOYS           |                    |           TOY_SERIES         |
+-----+----------------------+                    +---------+--------------------+
| PK  |  ID_TOY              |         +----------+ PK, FK1 |  ID_S              +--------+
|     |                      |         |          +------------------------------+        |
| FK1 |  ID_S                +---------+          |         |  ...               |        |
+----------------------------+                    |         |                    |        |
|     |  ...                 |                    |         |                    |        |
|     |                      |                    |         |                    |        |
+-----+----------------------+                    +---------+--------------------+        |
                                                                                          |
                                                                                          |
                                                                                          |
                                                                                          |
                                                  +------------------------------+        |
                                                  |         BR_SER_MEAS          |        |
                                                  +---------+--------------------+        |
                                                  | PK, FK1 |  ID_S              +--------+
                                                  |         |                    |
                                                  | PK, FK2 |  ID_M              +--------+
                                                  |         |                    |        |
                                                  | PK      |  ID_SEQ            |        |
                                                  |         |                    |        |
                                                  +---------+--------------------+        |
                                                                                          |
                                                                                          |
                                                  +------------------------------+        |
                                                  |        MEASURE_STEPS         |        |
                                                  +------------------------------+        |
                                                  | PK          ID_M             +--------+
                                                  +------------------------------+
                                                  |             PARAM_01         |
                                                  |             ...              |
                                                  |             PARAM_10         |
                                                  |                              |
                                                  |                              |
                                                  +------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort. It is an okay model, but the problem I have with this (if I understood you correctly) is that I need a predefined max. count of parameters.